# How does Matrix-scaling work?

Tags: android, matrix, native, scale

When calling `Matrix.postScale( sx, sy, px, py );` the matrix gets scaled and also translated (depending on the given point x, y). That predestines this method to be used for zooming into images because I can easily focus one specific point.

The android doc describes the method like this:

> Postconcats the matrix with the specified scale. M' = S(sx, sy, px, py) * M

At a first glance this seems ridiculous because M is supposed to be a 3x3-Matrix. Digging around I've found out that android uses a 4x4-Matrix for its computations (while only providing 3x3 on its API). Since [this code](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/Matrix.cpp) is written in C I'm having a hard time trying to understand what is actually happening.

What I actually want to know: How can I apply this kind of scaling (with a focused point) to the 3x3 Matrix that I can access within my Java-code?