# How does Matrix.postScale( sx, sy, px, py) work?

Tags: android, matrix, 2d

First read [Taig's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749802/how-does-matrix-scaling-work)

Taig said:

> When calling Matrix.postScale( sx, sy, px, py ); the matrix gets
>   scaled and also translated (depending on the given point x, y). That
>   predestines this method to be used for zooming into images because I
>   can easily focus one specific point.
>   The android doc describes the method like this:
>
> ```
> Postconcats the matrix with the specified scale. M' = S(sx, sy, px, py) * M
> ```
>
> At a first glance this seems ridiculous because M is supposed to be a
>   3x3-Matrix. Digging around I've found out that android uses a
>   4x4-Matrix for its computations (while only providing 3x3 on its API).
>   Since this code is written in C I'm having a hard time trying to
>   understand what is actually happening.

I saw the visual transform at [Wolfram](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Understanding2DScaling/)

My question is same as Taig

> What I actually want to know: How can I apply this kind of scaling
>   (with a focused point) to the 3x3 Matrix that I can access within my
>   Java-code?

Who can give me a example and 2d-scaling formula with 4 parameters (sx, sy, px, py) that a 10-year-old-kid would understand?

Comment: I found an explain at http://www.eoeandroid.com/thread-304325-1-1.html but I don't know Chinese

Comment: Don't understand your question.  Look up "affine transformation" and see if that gives you the formulas you're looking for.

Comment: M' = S(sx, sy, px, py) * M 
M is a 3x3 matrix. I don't know calculating

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look more closely at the Matrix methods.  You will see `getValue()` and `setValue()`.  The docs say they work with a `float` array with 9 values.  There are also a bunch of constants: `MSCALE_X`, `MSCALE_Y`, `MTRANS_X`, `MTRANS_Y` etc. etc.  Those constants are indices into the `float[9]` array.

Since we are only working in 2 dimensions, the matrix would actually be a *2x2* matrix.  But because this matrix supports *affine transforms*, the matrix is extended to become a 3x3 matrix.  3x3 = 9, which corresponds to the `float[9]` array.  That is, essentially, your 3x3 matrix.

The actual guts of `Matrix` are written in C++ and accessed through JNI because the operations have to be fast fast fast fast fast.  They even use a special non-standard floating point number format ("16.16") that is optimized for calculation speed.

I don't know where you are getting the information about a 4x4 array. Here's a code snippet from the C++ JNI:

```
SkScalar         fMat[9];
mutable uint32_t fTypeMask;

void setScaleTranslate(SkScalar sx, SkScalar sy, SkScalar tx, SkScalar ty) {
    fMat[kMScaleX] = sx;
    fMat[kMSkewX]  = 0;
    fMat[kMTransX] = tx;

    fMat[kMSkewY]  = 0;
    fMat[kMScaleY] = sy;
    fMat[kMTransY] = ty;

    fMat[kMPersp0] = 0;
    fMat[kMPersp1] = 0;
    fMat[kMPersp2] = 1;

    unsigned mask = 0;
    if (sx != 1 || sy != 1) {
        mask |= kScale_Mask;
    }
    if (tx || ty) {
        mask |= kTranslate_Mask;
    }
    this->setTypeMask(mask | kRectStaysRect_Mask);
}
```

It's a 3x3 matrix for an affine transform.

When you call `matrix.postScale()`, you are modifying scaleX, scaleY, transX, and transY.  (The `pre..()` and `post...()` methods preserve any transform that was in your matrix to start with.)  The `Matrix` applies the new transform like this:

```
X' = X * scaleX + transX
Y' = Y * scaleY + transY
```

That's the simplified version of the entire matrix multiplication.  If I have a figure with point (2,2) and I scale it 2x, the new point will be (4,4).  To move along the X or Y axis, I just add a constant.

Because `Matrix.postScale()` actually takes a focus point, the method internally adjusts transX & transY as though you are translating in, scaling, then translating back out. This makes the scaling appear as though the expansion/shrinking is centered around a point px, py.

```
transX = (1 - scaleX) * px
transY = (1 - scaleY) * py
```

So for the focus point, I move the figure to (px,py) by adding px and py directly to the original x,y values.  Then I do the scaling.  But to undo the translation, I have to take into account that my original focus point *is now scaled itself*, so instead of subtracting px and py, I have to subtract scaleX * px and scaleY * py.

*Skew* or *Shear* is like scaling but with opposing axes:

```
X' = Y * skewX
Y' = X * skewY
```

Since you're scaling and translating without warping, skewX and skewY are set to zero.  So they're still used in the matrix multiplication, they just don't affect the final outcome.

*Rotation* is done by adding in a little trig:

```
theta = angle of rotation
scaleX = cos(theta)
skewX = -sin(theta)
skewY = sin(theta)
scaleY = cos(theta)
```

Then there is the `android.graphics.Camera` (as opposed to `android.hardware.Camera`) that can take a 2D plane and rotate/translate it in 3D space.  This is where `MPERSP_0`, `MPERSP_1`, & `MPERSP_2` come into play.  I'm not doing those equations; I'm a programmer, not a mathematician.

But I don't need to be a mathematician.  I don't even need to know how `Matrix` does its calculations.  I have been working on an ImageView subclass that supports pinch/zoom.  So I use a `ScaleGestureDetector` to tell me when the user is zooming.  It has methods `getScaleFactor()`, `getFocusX()` and `getFocusY()`.  I plug those values into `matrix.postScale()`, and with my `ImageView` having a scale type set to `MATRIX`, I call `ImageView.setImageMatrix()` with my scaled matrix.  Voilà, the image zooms exactly the way the user expects to see it based on their gestures.

So I don't understand all the angst about grokking how `Matrix` works under the hood.  Still, I hope something I wrote here gives you the answers you are looking for.